# Toggling on the first click

Tags: javascript, toggle

I've tried two different methods of toggling the play/pause button on my player, neither of which work on the first click, for some reason.

This one, supposedly checks the status of the audio to see if it's paused or ended:

```
function togglePlayPause() { 
var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause"); 
if (audioPlayer.paused || audioPlayer.ended) { 
     playpause.title = "pause"; 
     playpause.innerHTML = "pause"; 
} 
else { 
         playpause.title = "play"; 
     playpause.innerHTML = "play"; 
     } 
}
```

Or I've tried this one, which just toggles via the onClick `toggle(this)`:

```
 function toggle(obj) {
    if (obj.className== 'playButton') {
        obj.className = 'pauseButton';
        obj.title = "PAUSE"; 
        obj.innerHTML = "PAUSE";
    } else {
        obj.className = 'playButton';
        obj.title = "PLAY"; 
        obj.innerHTML = "PLAY";
        }
    }
```

Neither toggle the first time the button is clicked, although the first method does change from the default inner "PLAY" to "play", so I guess that's something:

```
<a href="#" id="start" onclick="playPause();togglePlayPause();"><div title="play" class="playButton" id="playpause">PLAY</div></a>
```

In both methods, subsequent clicks work fine. Any idea why this is happening? Could it have something to do with the way the audioPlayer variable is called? The array starts from 0. (I'm clutching at straws.)

Many thanks as usual!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would go without creating functions, I would check if the link is clicked then proceed to the events that would be fired.

so something like `$("#start").click(function(){});` in can be tried.

First, have the jQuery library included in your HTML header.

Then create a new javascript file, included it as well (usually this is put after the jQuery included)

In your new javascript file write the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#start, #stop, #play, #pause").click(function() { //you can have more or less selectors (selectors are the ones with #)
       //Your code goes here
   });
});
```

Here is a fiddle for that solution. http://jsfiddle.net/JRRm2/1/ (tidier text: http://jsfiddle.net/JRRm2/2/)

Comment: There are also other buttons that need to change the state of the play/pause button subsequently. For example, there is a Stop and a Next button also need to know what state the play/pause button is in and will also toggle it. So, if the button is currently in a Pause state, Stop would change it to Play and if the button is in a Play state, Next would change it to Pause. Would just checking to see if the button has been clicked be enough?

Comment: no harder, you do `$("#start, #stop, #play, #pause").click(...` and the function will be triggered every time one of those buttons is clicked.

Comment: OK. I kind of have no idea how to write a click function (jquery, right?), but I'll see if I can figure something out...

Comment: I can't find any examples that make any sense to me. :-(        $('#start').click(function(){.html('Pause');}); Doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out how to toggle it back to Play when it's clicked again. The examples above were taken from code examples for the audio player I'm using. There must be some reason they used that method? The first one is from: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html

Comment: yes, what you need is the jQuery library.. I'll edit my code now and tell you the details

Comment: I don't really understand how to change or toggle the text in the divs with that. I tried http://api.jquery.com/html/ as I assume that's the jquery equivalent to innerHTML but it doesn't seem to work. I imagine there's something I'm missing. Sadly I can only work from quite literal examples.

Comment: OK, so what is the toggle going to do? Move div? Hide it or what?

Comment: Replace the text PLAY with PAUSE. Currently I'm using obj.innerHTML = "PAUSE"; It tests the div class: if the current class is "playButton", it changes it to "pauseButton" and changes the inner text from PLAY to PAUSE, and then toggles it vice versa.

Comment: OK, well that does work, but now I have to work out the logic for the other 2 buttons, the 6 playlists and the 32 tracks all of which toggle the play/pause button! I guess it's a good learning experience. Shame I don't understand what I'm looking at!  

Thank you.

Comment: you'll have lots of fun with jQuery, its not really hard to understand, if any questions that you try and can't do, ask here, but try to figure it out yourself